# nextcord.py Change Bot Activity per slash command (Python)

Tags: python, nextcord

I changed the activity of my discord bot, so that its set to "Listening to"
Now, i want to add a slash command that can manually change the activity
I have absolutely no idea how this could work xD

Im expecting, a command like this:
`/setbotstatus <ACTIVITY> <NAME>`
Member Permission is: `default_member_permissions=128`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Im asking for a slash command, that changes the bot activity (im using Python and Nextcord)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Assuming your `commands.Bot` instance is named `bot`*

## Creating the slash command

You can use the [@bot.slash_command](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.app_commands.CommandTree.command) decorator to create a slash command.

## Adding arguments to the command

`nextcord` automatically uses arguments passed to your command function to transform them into discord parameters, you just need to use [correct typing](https://docs.nextcord.dev/en/stable/api.html#slash-options) on the parameters.

## The code

```py
@bot.slash_command()
async def setbotstatus(interaction: nextcord.Interaction, activity: nextcord.SlashOption(choices={"Playing": nextcord.ActivityType.playing, "Watching": nextcord.ActivityType.watching, "Listening": nextcord.ActivityType.listening]), name: str):
    await interaction.client.change_presence(activity=nextcord.Activity(type=activity, name=name))
    await interaction.send("Activity changed")
```

You can add more parameters to the command, for example to set the bot's status to online, idle, do not disturb or offline.

Comment: Could you also tell me how to create that with the online/idle dnd or offline? Btw nice Code thanks!

Comment: You can use another parameter with SlashOption, replace choices with the one you have (online, idle, dnd, offline) and update the status in the `change_presence` function ;)